# Gradle Error while implementing firebase Auth and Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello: please can someone help me to fix this grade issue I kept seeing this error message "Error: Execution failed for task `:app:processDebugGoogleServices`.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0."`

Below is my app's gradle build settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.my12zone.apuw"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @Auwal  Check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is**

> You should not mix older support libs (eg `9.8.0` in your case) with newer support libs (eg. `10.0.1` in your case)

**Reson is**

Latest 10.0.1 version might have some newer function/features which might not even have definitions in older 9.8.0 lib.

This might lead to compilation errors or random crashes thus your Gradle build is failing.

**Solution is**

You should use latest Google play lib version from

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

along with latest firebase libs from

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Same goes with `com.android.support` libs

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
```

by

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

or

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks..!!! it works, although I have to change the complieSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 23 to 25 to fix another error.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer correct/upvote if it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: I did Thnks again